# I have an Error in use Spatie\MediaLibrary\IntercatsWithMedia; and use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia; in laravel after installing spatie media library

Tags: php, laravel, media

use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\IntercatsWithMedia;

class Post extends Model implements HasMedia
{
use HasFactory, IntercatsWithMedia;

}

**Error is following in Problems tab of VSCode**
Undefined type Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
Undefined type Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;

Comment: Did you `composer update`?

Comment: Error removed check my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Error removed I used following command in windows cmd in project folder instead of integrated cmd of vscode**
composer require filament/spatie-laravel-media-library-plugin:"^2.0"